Widget Launch to NavigationSplitView Detail
I'm trying to use NavSplitView and have a home screen or Lock Screen widget open the app to the tapped tool but my widget/navigation structure clearly needs to be adjusted.
@main
struct SparkysCircKitApp: App {
    @StateObject private var navManager = NavigationManager.shared
   
    @Namespace var animationNamespace
    
    @State private var selectedTool: Tool?
    
    let deviceType = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            if deviceType == .pad {
                iPadListView(animationNamespace: animationNamespace, selectedTool: selectedTool?.route)
                        .environmentObject(accentColorManager)
                        .environmentObject(calculatorViewModel)
                        .environmentObject(navManager)
                        .environmentObject(settingsViewModel)
                        .environmentObject(toolStore)
            } else {
             \\\ iPHONE VIEWS
        }
    }
        
    private func handleDeepLink(_ url: URL) {
        print("Handling deep link: \(url)")
        
        guard url.scheme == "sparky" else {
            print("Invalid URL scheme: \(url.scheme ?? "nil")")
            return
        }
        
        guard let host = url.host else {
            print("No host in URL")
            return
        }
        
        // Convert the hyphenated URL format back to a tool name
        let toolName: String
        if host == "nema-configurations" {
            toolName = "configurations"
        } else {
            toolName = host
                .replacingOccurrences(of: "-", with: " ")
                .localizedCapitalized
        }
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if toolName.lowercased() == "calculator" {
                navManager.isCalculatorPresented = true
            } else if toolName.lowercased() == "codeoftheday", let ruleNumber = url.pathComponents.last {
                NotificationCenter.default.post(
                    name: .showCodeOfTheDay,
                    object: ruleNumber
                )
            } else if let tool = toolStore.findTool(byName: toolName) {
                navManager.popToRoot()
                navManager.navigate(to: tool.route)
                selectedTool = tool
            } else {
                print("Could not find tool for name: \(toolName)")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct iPadListView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var navManager: NavigationManager
    @EnvironmentObject var toolStore: ToolStore
    
    @State private var selectedTool: ToolRoute? = nil

    var animationNamespace: Namespace.ID

    init(
        animationNamespace: Namespace.ID,
        selectedTool: ToolRoute?
    ) {
        self.animationNamespace = animationNamespace
        self.selectedTool = selectedTool
    }
    
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            List(selection: $selectedTool) {
\\\ LIST VIEW
        } detail: {
         if let toolRoute = selectedTool {
                ToolRouteView(route: toolRoute)
                    .environmentObject(accentColorManager)
                    .environmentObject(calculatorViewModel)
                    .environmentObject(navManager)
                    .environmentObject(settingsViewModel)
                    .environmentObject(toolStore)
            } else {
                ContentUnavailableView("Select a Tool",
                                       systemImage: "hammer.circle",
                                       description: Text("Choose a tool from the sidebar to get started"))
            }
        }

        .onChange(of: selectedTool) {
            navManager.activeRoute = selectedTool
        }

        .onOpenURL { url in
            handleWidgetDeepLink(url)
        }
    }
    
    private func handleWidgetDeepLink(_ url: URL) {
        print("Handling iPad widget deep link: \(url)")
        
        guard url.scheme == "sparky" else {
            print("Invalid URL scheme: \(url.scheme ?? "nil")")
            return
        }
        
        guard let host = url.host else {
            print("No host in URL")
            return
        }
        
        let toolName: String
        if host == "nema-configurations" {
            toolName = "configurations"
        } else {
            toolName = host
                .replacingOccurrences(of: "-", with: " ")
                .localizedCapitalized
        }
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if toolName.lowercased() == "calculator" {
                showingCalc = true
            } else if toolName.lowercased() == "codeoftheday", let ruleNumber = url.pathComponents.last {
                if let code = codes.first(where: { $0.ruleNumber == ruleNumber }) {
                    codeOfTheDay = code
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

I've tried using Notifications, passing the tool as a parameter and a few other variations but I can't seem to figure it out.
I've verified the URL scheme.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
